# PowerPivot Error When Using Custom SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, powerpivot

I built a query in SQL Server Management Studio 2012, which runs fine when tested.  However, when attempting to use this code in Power Pivot I receive the following error:

OLE DB or ODBC error.

```
An error occurred while processing table 'Query'.
The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.
```

Any thoughts on what could be invoking this error?

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @beginDate as DATE;
DECLARE @endDate as DATE;
DECLARE @tempTable AS TABLE(BusinessUnitID INTEGER, BusinessUnitName VARCHAR(255), SkillCode VARCHAR(255), 
                    Actuals INTEGER, DateCounted DATE)

DECLARE @count as INTEGER;

SET @beginDate = (SELECT MAX(DateCounted) FROM mmapps.dbo.t_EMS_BM_ActualsHistory);
SET @endDate = DATEADD(week,1,@beginDate);
SET @count = 0;

WHILE DATEADD(week,@count,@beginDate) < DATEADD(year,1,@beginDate)
BEGIN
    IF (@count = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @tempTable (BusinessUnitID,BusinessUnitName,SkillCode, Actuals, DateCounted)
        SELECT a.BusinessUnitID, a.BusinessUnitName, a.SkillCode, a.TotalHeads + 
            (
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM mmapps.dbo.t_EMS_BM_ChartData AS b 
            WHERE a.BusinessUnitID = b.BusinessUnitID AND a.SkillCode = b.SkillCode 
                AND b.ActivityTypeID BETWEEN 6 AND 10 AND b.SkillCode IS NOT NULL
                AND b.Date < @endDate) -
            (
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM mmapps.dbo.t_EMS_BM_ChartData AS b 
            WHERE a.BusinessUnitID = b.BusinessUnitID AND a.SkillCode = b.SkillCode 
                AND b.ActivityTypeID BETWEEN 6 AND 10 AND b.SkillCode IS NOT NULL
                AND b.Date < @endDate
            )
            AS Actuals

        ,DATEADD(week,@count,@beginDate) AS DateCounted
        FROM mmapps.dbo.t_EMS_BM_ActualsHistory AS a
        WHERE a.DateCounted = @beginDate
    END

    IF (@count > 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @tempTable (BusinessUnitID,BusinessUnitName,SkillCode, Actuals, DateCounted)
        SELECT a.BusinessUnitID, a.BusinessUnitName, a.SkillCode, a.Actuals + 
            (
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM mmapps.dbo.t_EMS_BM_ChartData AS b 
            WHERE a.BusinessUnitID = b.BusinessUnitID AND a.SkillCode = b.SkillCode 
                AND b.ActivityTypeID BETWEEN 6 AND 10 AND b.SkillCode IS NOT NULL
                AND b.Date >=@beginDate AND b.Date < @endDate) -
            (
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM mmapps.dbo.t_EMS_BM_ChartData AS b 
            WHERE a.BusinessUnitID = b.BusinessUnitID AND a.SkillCode = b.SkillCode 
                AND b.ActivityTypeID BETWEEN 6 AND 10 AND b.SkillCode IS NOT NULL
                AND b.Date >=@beginDate AND b.Date < @endDate
            )
            AS Actuals

        ,DATEADD(week,@count,@beginDate) AS DateCounted
        FROM @tempTable AS a
        WHERE a.DateCounted = (SELECT MAX(DateCounted) FROM @tempTable)
    END
    SET @count = @count + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @tempTable
ORDER BY DateCounted DESC
```

Comment: which kind of data source are you using?

Comment: All data is being extracted from SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit more research and trial and error, a simple addition of `SET NOCOUNT ON;` seemed to cure all my woes.